# Can I create a JSON example with empty values from only an object's type?

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

We are doing some stuff with webhooks and events. I want to create an example of a JSON payload based on the type of the event sent to the webhook.

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
public class TestClass{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Now what I would like, is to be able to create something like

```
{
    "id": 0
}
```

just from knowing `typeof(TestClass)`.

I do not want to create instances of my objects, because some of them are rather complex and have all sorts of parameter requirements.

I just want a JSON representation without any of the values filed in.

Any ideas?

Comment: `json.net` should be able to generate a schema based off a type. I've never tried, but this JSON.NET documentation link about [Generating Schemas](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm) may help you.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the exact thing im look for.

Comment: What do you want to do for complex properties?  For recursive data models?

Comment: Do you need an external tool or you need the C# code? You can try https://csharp2json.io

Comment: I need it to generate during runtime. For complex properties, im not sure yet, we have custom serializers for most of the types, but again, i cant use those because i dont have an instance of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Json.NET's [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) class to obtain a [`JsonContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract.htm) for the type you wish to serialize.  The contract defines how Json.NET serializes the type, and so can be used to generate a default representation.

A prototype implementation might looks something like the following:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    readonly static IContractResolver defaultResolver = new JsonSerializer().ContractResolver;

    public static string WriteDefaultValuesForTypeToString(Type type, IContractResolver resolver = null, Formatting formatting = Formatting.None)
    { 
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = formatting })
            {
                WriteDefaultValuesForType(type, jsonWriter, resolver);
            }
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static void WriteDefaultValuesForType(Type type, JsonWriter writer, IContractResolver resolver = null)
    { 
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings{ ContractResolver = resolver });
        WriteDefaultValuesForType(type, writer, serializer, null, 0);
    }

    static void WriteDefaultValuesForType(Type type, JsonWriter writer, JsonSerializer serializer, JsonProperty parent, int depth)
    { 
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(type);
        var defaultValue = parent?.DefaultValue;
        if (defaultValue == null && type.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) == null)
        {
            defaultValue = contract.DefaultCreator();
        }

        if (contract is JsonPrimitiveContract primitive)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, defaultValue);
        }
        else if (contract is JsonObjectContract obj)
        {
            if (depth > 0 && defaultValue == null)
            {
                writer.WriteNull();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();

                foreach (var p in obj.Properties)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(p.PropertyName);
                    WriteDefaultValuesForType(p.PropertyType, writer, serializer, p, depth++);
                }

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
        }
        else if (contract is JsonArrayContract array)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
        else if (contract is JsonDictionaryContract dict)
        {
            if (depth > 0 && defaultValue == null)
            {
                writer.WriteNull();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
        }
        else if (contract is Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonLinqContract linq)
        {
            /* What to do here? */
            writer.WriteNull();
        }
        else
        {
            //JsonISerializableContract, JsonDynamicContract, 
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unsupported contract {0}", contract));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can generate a default JSON for `TestClass` as follows:

```
var defaultJson = JsonExtensions.WriteDefaultValuesForTypeToString(typeof(TestClass), formatting : Formatting.Indented);
```

Notes:

- Unusual contracts such as [`JsonDynamicContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonDynamicContract.htm) or [`JsonISerializableContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonISerializableContract.htm) are not implemented yet.
- If a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) has been [applied](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_Converter.htm) to the type, there is no straightforward way to generate a default serialization absent calling [`WriteJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) and passing in an instance of the type.

  You *might* be able to use [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject) to generate an empty instance of your type without calling a constructor, and then pass that into `WriteJson()` to generate a default serialization.   No guarantee this will work though.  If the converter expects members such as collections to have been initialized by properly calling the constructor, an exception will likely be thrown.
- Similarly, there is no way to generate a default serialization for a type implementing [`ISerializable`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable) without an instance.
- If you are using camel case, you can pass `new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()` for the `resolver` argument.
- In the case of nested complex objects, `WriteDefaultValuesForType()` could be made recursive, however you will need to be careful to not overflow the stack in the case of recursive data models.
- As an alternative approach, you might consider generating and using a [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema) in your application.  See e.g. [Generating Schemas](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZYaPWA).